# BluetoothServerSocket.accept() won't return in the accept thread, while a Client socket is aquired

Tags: android, bluetooth, serversocket

So I have this Android Bluetooth Project and I get a really annoying problem;
Let me describe the context:

The two phones wich are to be connected aquire their BluetoothSockets using the exact method described in the bluetooth documentation on the android developers site ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html));
So, I use the following threads for the connection:

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
        // because mmServerSocket is final
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

That is the acceptthread and,

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

that is the ConnectThread;(you might notice that they really are copied from the upper link);

The problem is that when trying to connect, the connectthread actually returns a socket(calls managesocket()), but the accepting thread remains at socket = mmServerSocket.accept(), as if nothing would have happened;
But Something is acually happening in the AcceptThread, since as I initiate a Connection from the other device (the one with a ConnectThread) the logcat of the accepting device is being updated;
Sometimes the connection is actually properly created, but only after some force closing, disabling->enabling bluetoothh, etc.

here is an interesting line in the logcat(generated by the .accept() call, I supose):

07-19 18:04:47.484: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(3143): btlif_signal_event: ### event BTLIF_BTS_RFC_CON_IND not matched ###

So what could be the problem?